# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have imported scripts in the following order. Still I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function. Please help guys. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>       
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/SendStation/resources/assets/css/admin.css">
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
      $('#chart1').highcharts({
       //chart values
    });
});        
  </script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/o78mxg35/. Is the `$.highcharts is not a function` the only error in the console, or are there others? Normally errors like this are caused because the order of JS script includes is wrong, or another version of jQuery is added later in the page which overwrites the previous `$` implementation

Comment: Did you try to empty your cache? Do you have another version of jQuery imported?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan... I have fixed.. at the end of my html I have another Jquery script. now it is working fine. thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Yes it is because of another version of jQuery imported @pistou... Thanks